# How to fetch data from a Rails app and send it to TCP server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventmachine

I have a live Rails app and a separate ruby client-server application that sends and receives messages using [Eventmachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine). Both of these applications are working fine.

The goal is to fetch the data from live Rails app and send it to a TCP server. What is the best approach to integrate both these applications?

Comment: data are fetched and passed to the controller via `params`, take a look at the [ActionController](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html) documentation

Comment: I want to fetch data from Database and pass it to TCP server